# Unix Timestamp has a UTC difference

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, .net-core, epoch

I need to convert a Date and Time string to epoch timestamp. I am getting a time difference of 11 hours, (I reckon it is the UTC to local time difference).

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var output = StringDateToUnixString("08-02-2021 23:59:59", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Console.WriteLine($"Result : {output}");
        Console.WriteLine("Expected: 1612789199000");
        if(output == 1612789199000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not a match");
        }
    }
    
    public static double StringDateToUnixString(string dateString, string currentFormat)
    {
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, currentFormat, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return Convert.ToInt64((date - epoch).TotalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

[image: Sample from https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html]

When I check, epoch and local are in UTC, however (UTC-UTC).TotalMilliseconds, when converted back is local time.
I really appreciate I can update the StringDateToUnixString function so that the Main can work as expected.

Comment: So don't call `ToLocalTime`?

Comment: Still doesn't work. I ll update the question.

Comment: Why do you expect 1612789199000

Comment: Because when I convert that, I am getting "08-02-2021 23:59:59". I have added the screenshot from https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html

Comment: Try another site

Comment: Its the same. The expected timestamp that I need is for local, not GMT.

Comment: "The expected timestamp that I need is for local, not GMT." - then you don't actually want a Unix timestamp. Unix timestamps measure a number of seconds from the Unix epoch, which was 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Your expected value represents 2021-02-T12:59:59Z. Your code is correctly converting a string value *expressing a UTC date/time* into a Unix timestamp, but it sounds like that's not what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this. for get unix timestamp:

```
DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

and for convert timestamp to date time:

```
return new DateTimeOffset(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero).AddMilliseconds(1612789199000).UtcDateTime;
```

Comment: Didn't work, unless you want to provide me with full code. I might be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because you are subtracting two `DateTime` values that have different meanings.  Your `epoch` variable is UTC based and has its `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Utc`, while your `date` variable is local-time based and has its `Kind` property set to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

***However***, when subtracting or comparing `DateTime` values - the `Kind` property is not considered.  The operation is based solely on the `Ticks` property.

Contrast this with `DateTimeOffset` values, where the offset *is* taken into account for such operations.

There are a few different ways you could resolve this in your code, and still adjust from a local-time based date/time string to a Unix Timestamp (which is inherently UTC based):

- You could convert the `date` value to UTC after parsing it, before subtracting:

  ```
  DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, currentFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  return (dateTime.ToUniversalTime() - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
  ```
- You could tell `DateTime.ParseExact` that you'd like a behavior where the input string is assumed to be local time and the output value should be adjusted to UTC.  This is done by combining the `AssumeLocal` and `AdjustToUniversal` `DateTimeStyles` flags as follows:

  ```
  DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, currentFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
      DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
  return (dateTime - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
  ```
- You could parse the value as a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`.  When doing so, if no offset is in the input string, the local time zone is used.  This approach also has the advantage of being able to use the built-in `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` method:

  ```
  DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, currentFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  return dateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  ```

Note in all three cases, I assumed `using System.Globalization;` was included at the top of your program, and that I removed `Convert.ToInt64` from the result because it is extraneous.